# Estimate position and Width/Height of rendered UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a `UserControl` (boxes) that can have varying size based on the number of items in its `ItemsControl`.
Many such usercontrols are added to a `Canvas` programmatically.

I need to draw arrows interconnecting these usercontrols. What is the best way to get the origin coordinates of the control w.r.t the `Canvas` and the rendered `Width`/`Height` so that I can figure out the arrow start and endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

`Canvas` provides the coordinates of each control via `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties - which you know if you positioned them yourself anyway. So the (slightly) harder part is getting the other coordinate, and for that you want to know the rendered height/width. `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` give you this, assuming the control has already been laid out:

```
double top = Canvas.GetTop(control)
double bottom = top + control.ActualHeight
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(control)
double right = left + control.ActualWidth
```

If you're doing this before the controls have had a chance to be rendered on the screen, you can first do `control.UpdateLayout()` (or `control.Measure()`) to ensure the layout system measures their size.