# Getting Actual Size of UserControl before rendering

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to get the ActualSize of `MyUserControl` before it gets rendered using `Measure` methode of `UserControl` class as suggested for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660861/get-rendered-size-of-usercontrol-in-a-canvas). However it is not working. `MyUserControl` has an `ItemsControl` that is databound with a `List` as shown below. The items added through `uc.MyCollection = myCollection;` is not getting reflected in `uc.DesiredSize.Height`.

```
MyUserControl uc= new MyUserControl();
uc.AName = "a1";
uc.Width = 194;
uc.MyCollection = myCollection; //myCollection is  a List databound to ItemsControl inside MyUserControl
uc.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
uc.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, uc.DesiredSize.Width, uc.DesiredSize.Width)); //Needed?
uc.UCHeight = uc.DesiredSize.Height; //size of items databound to ItemsControl not reflected here
uc.UCWidth = uc.DesiredSize.Width;
uc.Margin = new Thickness(34, 42, 0, 0);
myRoot.Children.Add(uc); //myRoot is Canvas
```

Comment: Try adding the `uc` to the root before invoking `Mesaure()` and do a `UpdateLayout()` before accessing the `DesiredSize`. Thats what I usually do.

Comment: @neutrino: what is not working?  The values are. 0 or are not exact?

Comment: values are not exact. The height doesn't take into account the height dues to the items in the itemscontrol

Comment: Is your ListBox inside a Canvas? Canvas does not size itself based on it's Visual parent or children, and it's DesiredSize is 0 if not explicitly set.

Answer (score 6):

You have to override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride in your uc to calculate the size for your own. Inside MeasureOverride "ask" your List with "Measure" of its own size - so you can calculate the size for your own uc (returning this size in MeasureOverride) - then you get your DesiredSize after calling uc.Measure.

Comment: I am pretty sure you only have to implement these methods on custom panel implementations. A UC is simply a composite of other controls, so it is not necessary to implement these.

Comment: What if the user control has an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a `List`? After creating the usercontrol, I am setting assigning the `List` property to which `ItemsControl` of `UserControl` is bound. The problem is that the `Measure` call on usercontrol returns the `DesiredSize.Height` without taking into account the Height of the `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ItemsControl binding to MyCollection will not process until your user control is in the VisualTree, so at the point you call Measure, the desiredsize is still 0.

When I need to get the size of a FrameworkElement, I set it's Opacity to 0, add it to the visual tree, and wait for the SizeChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx
The parameter "**byval e as PaintEventArgs**" in the example **is not needed**. In order to only retrieve the size needed to show the whole string, you can create your own paintEventArgs field in the subroutine MeasureStringMin.